# Calculating Equilibria for a 3 ODE system with 11 unknown parameters i.e. Looking For the intersection points of 3 surfaces.

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I have the following system of 3 ODEs of 3 variables $(\ell,M,h)$ and 11 parameters $(\sigma_{\ell},\mu_{\ell},d_{\ell},\sigma_M,\alpha_1,\beta,\alpha_2,\nu_M,\sigma_h,\nu_h,d_h)$:

$\frac{d\ell}{dt}=\sigma_{\ell} - \mu_{\ell}\frac{M \ell}{1+\ell} - d_{\ell} \ell$,
$\frac{dM}{dt}=\sigma_M\left(\alpha_1\frac{\ell}{\beta+\ell} +\alpha_2\frac{M \ell}{1+\ell} \right) - \nu_M \frac{Mh}{1+h} $,
$\frac{dh}{dt}=\sigma_h-\nu_h \frac{Mh}{1+h} - d_h h$.

To find any possible equilibria I clearly need to look for the intersection of the nullclines of the system. These nullclines graphed are 3 surfaces in $(\ell,M,h)$ space. The issue is that I have 11 unknown parameters and the only restrictions on them (and the variables) are that they be real and either zero or positive.

I considered that it may be possible to write a matlab or mathematica script where I could vary the parameters and get it to output excatly when an intersection occurs (ie when all of the above equations are zero on the right-hand-side).

This question is certainly vague, and I would welcome any range of mathematical/computational techniques that could be useful for this problem.
Cheers!

Comment: First of all, reduce the number of parameters :) I understand that each parameter has its own meaning in the (applied) problem that you want to solve, but from mathematical viewpoint carrying all of them might be an extra burden. It's called a nondimensionalization, you might want to take a look at Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization . For the second step (namely, finding equilibria coordinates) I'd rather recommend to try symbolic computations first: I hope that symbolic engine might do the job, because system doesn't look too terrifying.

Comment: @Evgeny. I have attempted nondimensionalizing the problem, but I found that I am only able to reduce the problem by one parameter. Furthermore, using Reduce and Solve in Mathematica to find these intersection solutions has been less than profitable. Basically, trying to find these solutions over the Reals is impossible for my computer. I tried to run the code but I ended up aborting the processes after 3 hrs of my laptop giving it a good go.

Comment: Yep, I've overlooked that denominators don't behave nice w.r.t. scaling of variables. You know, I think that you might obtain quite tractable formulas if you express $\frac{Ml}{1+l}$ and $\frac{Mh}{1+h}$ from 1st and 3rd equations, substitute them into 2nd equation and express $h$ as function of $l$. Could you try that?

Comment: Sorry could you explain what you mean by "express $\frac{Ml}{1+l}$ and $\frac{Mh}{1+h}$ from 1st and 3rd equations etc..."

Comment: This is too obvious, but okay, I'll explain: $\frac{Mh}{1+h} = \frac{\sigma_h - d_h \cdot h}{\nu_h}$, $\frac{Ml}{1+l} = \frac{\sigma_l - d_l \cdot l}{\mu_l}$. If you replace $\frac{Mh}{1+h}$ and $\frac{Ml}{1+l}$ by these expressions and rearrange terms in second equation for equilibrium states, you'll get $h = \frac{\sigma_h}{d_h} - \frac{\sigma_M \nu_h}{d_h \cdot \nu_M}\left( \alpha_1 \cdot \frac{l}{\beta+l} + \frac{\alpha_2}{\mu_l} \left ( \sigma_l - d_l \cdot l \right) \right)$ (check yourself, correctness isn't guaranteed). After few manipulations you should get an equation for $l$ only.

Comment: * Maybe I used the wrong word for describing this manipulation and it should be called "solve for $\frac{Mh}{1+h}$ ". I'd be glad if someone will point me to the right term for it :)

Comment: @Evgeny any chance you could should where to go from 
$$ h=\dfrac{\sigma_h}{d_h}−\dfrac{\sigma_M \nu_h}{d_h \nu_M} \left(\alpha_1⋅\dfrac{l}{\beta+l}+\dfrac{\alpha_2}{\mu_l}(\sigma_l−d_l⋅l) \right) $$. I can't see how to rearrange another expression for $h$ in terms on $l$, and thus I cannot see how to manipulate the $h=...$ equation to achieve an equation for $l$ only.

Comment: Plug this "$h$ in terms of $l$" back to the 3rd equation.... you'll get quadratic or cubic equation for $l$.

Comment: @Evgeny what about $M$ in the third equation? Please show me how, because I cannot see it happening.

Comment: You can get it from the first equation as an expression in $l$.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Evgeny. I get a rather intractable quintic in $\ell$. I think my analysis stops there.

Comment: This is bad... I hoped that it would be at most cubic. Maybe it's still possible to study the amount of root in given interval, but I'll try to take a look at this later.